absorption of carbon dioxide in water of different pH
As part of a middle-school class, discussing the oceans' acidification,
I'm trying to show at home, that alkaline water absorb more CO2 than acidic water.
My plan was to have distilled or salted water solutions, with different pH, and blow CO2 into those solutions.
I hoped to be able to have an indicator that shows the CO2 level changes in each solution. However, using the CO2 indicator I have for my aquarium, it changed colors immediately according to the acid/base solutions, even before I started blowing CO2.
I'm looking at a chemical test kit (HI3818) by Hanna Instruments, that measures carbon dioxide by titration with sodium hydroxide. I'm not sure if that kit can help me, as it adds a base to my solution, which might change the results.
I appreciate any advice on how to achieve my goal at home and in a reasonable budget?

What pH does your aquarium pH indicator change colors at?  One idea would be to let it change as you add alkali, blow CO2 into the water just until the color changes, and then measure CO2 by adding calcium nitrate or barium nitrate to excess.  Calcium (or barium) carbonate will precipitate, and if you quantify the precipitate, you can quantify the amount of CO2.

I would use the titration by NaOH on phenolphthalein before and after CO2 bubbling. the difference would be proportional to the added CO2, converted by titration to NaHCO3. Obviously, not much usable for too alkalic solutions.

Thank you both for your suggestions
